# Restricting Matplotlib Legend Best Location options

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

In Matplotlib, the legend has a parameter `loc` that allows to specify the location of the legend.

The user can force the legend to be in 9 different locations or let matplotlib decide where is the best location for the Legend.

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html):

> The strings 'upper left', 'upper right', 'lower left', 'lower right'
> place the legend at the corresponding corner of the axes/figure.
>
> The strings 'upper center', 'lower center', 'center left', 'center
> right' place the legend at the center of the corresponding edge of the
> axes/figure.
>
> The string 'center' places the legend at the center of the
> axes/figure.
>
> The string 'best' places the legend at the location, among the nine
> locations defined so far, with the minimum overlap with other drawn
> artists.

Now, I want to force the legend to be on the right part of the plot, but depending on the data, the best location could be 'upper right' or 'lower right'.

I don't want the legend to be placed on the left or on the center, but I still want the best location between 'upper right' or 'lower right' to be calculated.

According to the documentation the Best location is calculated by calculating `the minimum overlap with other drawn artists`

Is there a way of limiting the `best` option to take only certain options in account and not among the nine locations? Or to manually call the function that calculates this overlap with only the desired options?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying the underlying matplotlib code

Comment: A trick could be to put some dummy fully transparent objects on the undesired spots.

Comment: I don't like the idea of dummy objects. Not only looks like a dirty hack, but also putting some dummy points is not enough, there have to be more dummy points than real points in the locations where I want the legend. Otherwise the dummy points will still be the best location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the area that matplotlib considers for the [calculation of the best position](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c57c8781a7b9d8e5e9ece7c4cb8acee3b692f7f2/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L978) by using the `bbox_to_anchor` keyword:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

x = np.arange(10)
ax1.plot(x, x**2, label="best location")
ax1.legend(loc="best")    

ax2.plot(x, x**2, label="best right location")
#bbox signature (left, bottom, width, height) 
#with 0, 0 being the lower left corner and 1, 1 the upper right corner
ax2.legend(loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(0.6, 0., 0.4, 1.0)) 

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll take a look and try it. Thanks

Comment: Nicely done finding this method!